# My listview is overlaying the line below Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

I have a list where, on Android and iOS, it works correctly listing the items each in its line, because when I run in Windows Universal Mobile the items when they are very large, it overlaps the line below, how can I solve this?

```
 <ListView x:Name="List" ItemsSource="{Binding List}"  HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None" IsRefreshing="False" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell >
                    <Grid Padding="5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackLayout HeightRequest = "80" WidthRequest="80">
                            <Image x:Name="Image" BackgroundColor="#38B6AB" Scale="1.0" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Image.Source>
                                    <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding Imagem}" CacheValidity="5" CachingEnabled="True"/>
                                </Image.Source>
                            </Image>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Spacing="4"  VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="{Binding nome}" TextColor="#38B6AB"  FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Data}" TextColor="#666666" FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding hora}" TextColor="#474747" Font="Bold" FontSize="Small" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

With the illustration of my design the 1 line overlaps the 2 line
[image]

Comment: Try putting a HeightRequest to the Grid (the root of List Item template). You indicated `HasUnevenRows="True"` to the ListView but the `Grid` doesn't have any size.

Comment: I tested with your code but has no problem. Could you share a simple demo？

Comment: This solved the placement of the HighRequest